# UAE tourism visa photos mixed up

Tags: visas, paperwork, uae

My sister and I applied for a 30-day tourism visa for UAE. When we finally got the visas, our photos were mixed up (my photo is on my sister's visa and my sister's photo is on mine).

All other information is correct and the passport numbers are correct. Will there be any issue? We will be leaving together at the same time.

Comment: I suspect airline and Immigration officers will likely expect the photos to match the passport…

Comment: Asked another way: when the Immigration Officer sees that the person in the passport photo _is a different person_ from the person in the visa photo, how could it **not** be an issue?

Comment: For a normal country, if you get through the airport checks and manage to fly, I can imagine that the immigration would deal with the problem at the airport but it would be a lot of hassle fot you and a very long wait. But for UAE the immigration is very strict being an Islamic country.